# flutter _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, e-commerce

when i click on a single product link it throws this error:

```
_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

and vscode sends cursor to this line:

'''final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;'''

i changed ? to ! sign and that gives same error
```

Comment: Remove the `as String`  cast

Answer (score 0):

Your line should be:

final productId = ModalR`enter code here`oute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as String?;

Answer (score 0):

your productId returns null, please first try make to make sure that productId is not null.Don't force ! without checking for null.